# Login failed message does not appear on a website while using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to log in into a website using selenium.The end site provides a access denied message if i enter wrong credentials and submit the login form(without selenium).But when i do the same stuff using selenium,the access denied message does not appear. Any suggestions?

URL : https://oa.lombardfinance.com.au/

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    driver.get("https://oa.lombardfinance.com.au/");
    driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtClientNumber")).sendKeys("Subrat");
    driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPassword")).sendKeys("Subrat");
    driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtCaptcha")).sendKeys("Subrat");
    //WebElement loginForm = driver.findElement(By.id("aspnetForm"));
    //js.executeScript("arguments[0].submit();", loginForm);

    WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnLogin2"));
    new Actions(driver).moveToElement(login).click().perform();
```

Comment: Can you post the code of your selenium tests, and the HTML of the corresponding web page(s)?

Comment: I have attached the code and url.

Comment: Hm. I see what you mean, the "Access Denied" message appears when you click manually, but not when Selenium clicks.  I'm _guessing_ it is related to the fact you are clicking an input with type of file, which then executes some javascript, but I can't get it to work by trying to execute that javascript in the test. ie   `driver.executeScript('WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnLogin2", "", true, "lo", "", false, false))');`. Sorry I can't be more help, hopefully someone else can step in.

Comment: **Thanks for the effort**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tried the same code you're using with a slight difference in driver initiation:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "\path\to\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

I excluded the line:
    **options.addArguments("disable-infobars");**
and the Selenium test shows Access denied as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code:

```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe");
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.addArguments("--test-type");
  options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

The solution is more convenient one because some times browser shows developer mode issue.